# With an angularjs ng-repeat, can I force one element to be first in the list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array, `keywords`, printing with an ng-repeat:

```
 <li ng-repeat="keyword in keywords"> {{ keyword }} </li>
```

Which when it's sorted alphabetically would display, e.g:

```
 Apples
 Cucumbers
 Daikon
 Turnip
```

I want that when a user searches a specific keyword, that keyword gets "pinned" to the top of the list, no matter how else the list is sorted. So if the user searches "Turnip", Turnip is first in the list, while the rest remains sorted alphabetically:

```
Turnip
Apples
Cucumbers
Daikon
```

I am wondering if this functionality is possible with ng-repeat, or if I will need to construct it by inserting an additional element at the top and then filtering just that one from the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm adding another answer, as I think both could be used, but this one with sorting is much slicker!

Here, I just do a sort of the array of objs on the pinned first then on the name value as you wanted it:

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in array | orderBy:['pinned','name']:reverseSort ">{{ obj.name }} [<label>Pin</label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.pinned" ng-click="pinObj(obj)" />]</li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8NGW3b?p=info

Cheers

Comment: Both methods are good examples of the two approaches I had in mind, but this one is much slicker and avoids clunky mark-up (there's a lot going on inside that ng-repeat that I don't want to duplicate), so it's the one I'll use. Effort & examples very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom angular filter that handles the sorting. Then you could just use

```
<li ng-repeat="keyword in keywords|my_sort"> {{ keyword }} </li>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I could imagine that you could have instead of just a key in your array, you could have an array of objects for example:

```
array {
   [ key: "Turnip",
     pinned: true],

   [ key: "Apples",
     pinned: false] }
```

And then, in your ng-repeat, then you could have a filter that splits out the pinned versus unpinned as required.

```
app.filter('pinned', function() {

   return function (list, pinned, scope) {

      var test = (pinned == 'true' ? true : false);
      var returnArray = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         if (list[i].pinned === test) {
           returnArray.push(list[i]);
         }
      }

    return returnArray; 
  };
});
```

I've created this plunk to show what I mean above. A potentially slicker solution would be to sort your array by the pinned attribute.

http://plnkr.co/edit/onFG7K61gLLqX31CgnPi?p=preview